# Is there a word or term for a PIVOT without data loss?

Tags: sql, database, pivot, pivot-table, terminology

Is there a word/phrase that describes the following action?

Where data in the form:

```
ID   |Group |Type  |Data
------------------------
1    |A     |a     |10
2    |A     |b     |11
3    |A     |c     |12
4    |B     |a     |20
5    |B     |d     |40
6    |C     |b     |31
```

Is transformed to this form:

```
Type |A     |B     |C    (etc.)
-------------------------
a    |10    |20    |NULL
b    |11    |NULL  |31
c    |12    |NULL  |NULL
d    |NULL  |40    |NULL
```

This is a kind of pivot, but where there is no summarising so data could (in theory) be updated via the transformed table.

I would have thought that this is needed quite widely for allocation of resources/stock to multiple projects. In the example above 'Group' would be project, 'Type' would be the resource and 'Data' would be the quantity needed or allocated.

I really want to ask a question about how this is normally approached in database design, but I need to know the terminology before I can do that!

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. However, this is a conceptual question about terminology so shouldn't be DBMS specific.

Comment: The method for solving this is to use dynamic SQL, so this is often referred to as "dynamic pivot".  Some databases have better support than others.